# AWS machine learning prediction schema problems

Tags: machine-learning, aws

I've trained an AWS Machine Learning model with the training data from here : https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

I'm now trying to run a batch prediction with the test data from the same source but I get the following error when I try to load the data : "  The schema in this data file must match the datasource used to create the ML model ml-xxxxxxxxx. Ensure that the data file you are using matches the schema structure."

The schema, as far as I can see, is identical. I have tried it with and without the 'survived' column which is the value I'm trying to predict. I even tried it with the same training set which obviously has an identical schema and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today, tried googling for people having the same issue and found your question.

I solved my problem by creating the data source first and then running the prediction from there. So, instead of selecting the following option,

`Batch Predictions > Create new batch prediction > ML model for batch prediction > My data is in S3, and I need to create a datasource`

which fails, I first did:

`Datasources > Create a new datasource...`

Next, I ran the batch prediction from an existing datasource successfully.

Answer (score 0):

One common reason that the schemas do not match up is that if you use the AML service to infer the attributes.  I just found this as the root cause in my two data sets.  In my test file, several attributes were inferred to be Numeric or Binary - when they were the opposite.  Be sure to use the schema from your training data set to check the inferred schema of subsequent (test, eval, etc.) data sources.